# Configuring /etc/hosts file

Tags: 14.04, configuration, hosts

I am running 14.04 x64 vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic and I face a problem after updating `/etc/hosts` file. Here is the content of the file:

```
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.    
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist    
# then you will need to either    
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.tmpl    
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data

127.0.1.1 mydomain.com
127.0.0.1 localhost

/# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts  ::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback  fe00::0 ip6-localnet 

ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix     
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes     
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters     
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

I have a website and a web app on the website which are running just fine right after rebooting the server, but after a couple of minutes, I get an error that the connection to database could not be establsihed. Once I reboot the server, it works fine for a couple of minutes again.

Now I am very new to navigating/managing ubuntu server, so if there is any other valuable information I could provide, just ask for it.